# Creating a Python local server in Windows

Tags: command-line, python

I'm trying to use this commmand:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

but it's not working. I'm guessing that it isn't working because I'm running that through Windows Command Prompt. How does one make that function?

The error I am getting from Command Prompt is: 
"'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: "its not working" is not very helpful in debugging an issue.  What is the specific error are you getting?

Comment: "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 3):

By default, `python` is not registered as a command in the windows command prompt. (Be it a file in the `PATH`, a macro or something else entirely).

The solution is to simply type the whole path to the `python.exe`. I installed Python to `C:\Python27` so all I need to type is

```
C:\Python27\python.exe /m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: That did it. And then I added it to `PATH`, because that's easier.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error you provided, it looks like you didn't add Python to your path environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you recently installed Python 3.x, try searching for "Python" in windows file explorer.  Mine was installed under:
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\

Use Command prompt to navigate to this directory, and then type "Python.exe - m http.server"

You should be good to go.